# Warning Duplicate Service Exception jBoss EAP 6.4

Tags: java, mysql, jboss

Im runing my server and i get this warning, i think this give me an another problem with mysql later, so if someone can help me with this, please, thanks

```
12:01:56,835 WARN  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-4) 
JBAS010402: Unable to instantiate driver class "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver": 
org.jboss.msc.service.DuplicateServiceException: 
Service jboss.jdbc-driver.RecoverOnline_warcom_mysql_jdbc_Driver_5_1 is already registered
```

I try to delete the folder of my project on deployements and run it again, but doenst work, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your MySQL module should be separate and added to the JBoss 6 installation you are using. Multiple applications and part of your code can this single module.

Your code should depend on the module, for example using the Maven provided dependency scope level.

Does that help?